# Where is source code of agora_rtc_sdk.dll

Tags: uwp, capture

How do I capture uwp app screen?

Comment: Have you checked this git [source](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Electron-SDK)？

Answer (score 0):

> how to capture uwp app screen?

Derive from official document,

> Starting in Windows 10, version 1803, the Windows.Graphics.Capture namespace provides APIs to acquire frames from a display or application window, to create video streams or snapshots to build collaborative and interactive experiences.
>
> With screen capture, developers invoke secure system UI for end users to pick the display or application window to be captured, and a yellow notification border is drawn by the system around the actively captured item. In the case of multiple simultaneous capture sessions, a yellow border is drawn around each item being captured.

For more detail please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture).